# Stream function calls are async in Google Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-async

Why dart calls my function "aFunction" after Step2? If I execute this code this text below in console:

Step2
Step1

My code:

```dart
void main()
{
 ...
 stream.listen(aFunction);
 print("Step2");
 ...
}

void aFunction()
{
 print("Step1");
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: They're part of `dart:async` but you find it confusing that they're asynchronous?

Comment: Because... they are asynchronous? As you seem to know, seeing as you added the async tag to your question? Why exactly would you expect `Step1` being printed before `Step2`?

Comment: From what your code shows I wonder why 'Step1' is printed at all. `aFunction` should be only called when `stream` emits an element.
`Step2` is printed synchronuosly (immediately).

Comment: I would like call my function sync. It is possible?

Comment: Well, no. https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/ --> `Once a Dart function starts executing, it continues executing until it exits. In other words, Dart functions can’t be interrupted by other Dart code.` In other other words, everything that should happen after `print("Step1")` should be added to `aFunction()`.

Comment: Shouldn't `aFunction` take an argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the few promises that a Dart Stream makes is that it generates no events in response to a listen call.
The events may come at a later time, but the code calling 'listen' is allowed to continue, and complete, before the first event is fired.
We originally allowed streams to fire immediately on a listen, but when we tried to program with that, it was completely impossible to control in practice.

The same is true for listening on a future, for example with 'then'. The callback will never come immediately.

Events should generally act as if they were fired by the top-level event loop, so the event handler doesn't have to worry if other code is running - other code that might not be reentrant.

That is not always the case in practice. One event handler may trigger other events through a synchronous stream controller, effectively turning one event into anoter. That requires the event handler to know what it is doing. Synchronous controllers are intended for internal use inside, e.g., a stream transformer, and using a synchronous stream controller isn't recommended in general.

So, no, you can't have the listen call immediately trigger the callback.

Comment: That's interesting, I always tried to code as if the callback could be called directly if the callback was already triggered. I probably didn't do it right, but it's interesting that it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to a stream synchronously if you created a [StreamController](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.StreamController) with the **sync** option enabled. Here is an example to get what you describe:

```
var controller = new StreamController<String>(sync: true);
var stream = controller.stream.asBroadcastStream();
stream.listen((text) => print(text));
controller.add("Step1");
print("Step2");
```